# how to add post meta for share count in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, share, counter

I am using this code for the display share counter;

```
function facebook_share() {
  $post_id = get_the_ID();
$url = get_permalink( $post_id );

    $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url );
    if( !is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
      $json = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
      return isset( $json->shares ) ? $json->shares : 0;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }

}

function googleplus_share() {
      $post_id = get_the_ID();
$url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://clients6.google.com/rpc', array(
      'body' => '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]',
      'headers' => array(
        'content-type' => 'application/json'
      )
    ));
    if( !is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
      $json = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
      if( !isset( $json[0]->error ) ) {
        return $json[0]->result->metadata->globalCounts->count;

      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

function social_shares() {

  $fb = facebook_share();
  $google = googleplus_share();
  $totalcounts = $fb + $google;
  return $totalcounts;
}
```

but it's too slow because always calculating the total share so I want to save the total shares number as **post meta** in database...Then I will show the number of total share from database

thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this relates to a post use `update_post_meta` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

To save your count against the id of the post in your function - which I assume you will run via a cron task etc...

Then on your post template use `get_post_meta`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

To display the count.

Comment: hey @Simon thanks for answer can I make it with the advanced custom fields plugin?

Comment: I believe so, I don't use that plugin myself but you can save custom data against posts with it. However I personally would say you don't need it as you already have your social data code and you can just hook into that. You only need the two functions I showed you, which ACF would be using itself anyways.

Comment: I believe update will "add" if it does not already exist, so you can just use that :)